# Go Unmarshal reflect.Type got map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, go

I want to convert json string to some struct ,use as func param
  I use reflect to get Param Type,this work fine ,
  but if I use `json.Unmarshal` I always get `map[string]interface{}`

this is a mini Run sample,File name is `json_test.go`

```
package testJson

import (
    "reflect"
    "encoding/json"
    "testing"
    "log"
)

type LoginForm struct {
    Name string
}

func Login(login LoginForm) {

}

func TestRun(t *testing.T) {
    _func := Login
    f := reflect.ValueOf(_func)
    funcType := f.Type()
    paramType := funcType.In(0)
    log.Print(paramType.Name())
    v := reflect.New(paramType).Elem().Interface()
    jsonstr := `{"Name":"123"}`
    log.Print(jsonstr)
    log.Print(reflect.TypeOf(v).Name())
    log.Print("%+v", v)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Print(reflect.TypeOf(v).Name())
    log.Print( v)
    var in []reflect.Value
    in = make([]reflect.Value, funcType.NumIn())
    in[0] = reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f.Call(in)
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You must show all relevant code. Please show a runnable minimal example.

Comment: add the runnable  example ,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't `reflect.New` a pointer type because the result of that is a pointer to the pointer, instead `reflect.New` the `Elem` of the pointer type.

Change this:

```
v := reflect.New(paramType).Elem().Interface()
```

To this:

```
v := reflect.New(paramType.Elem()).Interface()
```

At this point `v` is already a pointer to `LoginForm` so you don't need to get its address with `&` when passing to `Unmarshal`.

https://play.golang.org/p/JM4fRXb7fo

---

Also the reason you got `map[string]interface{}` is because the return type of the `Interface()` method is unsurprisingly enough `interface{}`, so while `v`'s underlying type could be anything its "topmost" type is `interface{}`. So then, doing `&v` will get you `*interface{}` as opposed to the inteded `*LoginForm`. And in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) you can find that trying to unmarshal a JSON object into an `interface{}` will result in a value of type `map[string]interface{}`.